# Django rest framework partial update (PATCH)

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to do a partial update of a user so that not all the fields should be sent in a request. For this I have created a view like this:

```
elif request.method == 'PATCH':
    user_serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    if user_serializer.is_valid():
        user_serializer.save()
        return Response({'message': 'User updated correctly'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have seen that if the partial = True parameter is activated then it will call the partial_update () function of the serializer, but it does not:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print("partial update")
```

So, how can I do this partial_update to update a user field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the serializer to the view:

```
serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Then you can get the serializer from the view instance:

```
user_serializer = self.get_serializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
user_serializer.save()
```

Finally `partial_update` method should be triggered at view level.